# Really long Ubuntu 20.04 load time

Tags: boot, 20.04

After almost breaking down my Ubuntu os and then recovering from the mess, I found that the start-up time had increased manifolds up to somewhere around 5 mins...

After running `dmesg` in the terminal (which I believe outputs the log of the Ubuntu start-up with square brackets denoting the time:

1. I found some ACPI BIOS Bugs and ACPI errors at around 0.400000, However they do not look like they are taking up too much time... about some milliseconds
2. However, upon scrolling down to about the 100's some of the processes seem like they are taking 5, 10, 20 seconds...

Is there a way to trace or remove these errors, bugs and programs which are slowing the system down so much?

Note: Everything updated

This is the log output... I am going to only paste the places where I think the lines might indicate the cause of the problem because the whole log is too long.

(People who want to look at the complete log:  https://justpaste.it/4rnkq)

(if you want to look at systemd-analyse blame output:  https://justpaste.it/9ry4r)

```
##########################################################################
Next Problem (what are all these ACPI errors and Bugs??)
##########################################################################
[    0.475113] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475119] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475120]   Local0: 0000000045694f77 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
[    0.475124] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475125]   Arg0:   0000000044228069 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475128] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475133] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475176] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475179] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475180]   Local0: 0000000017585386 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
[    0.475182] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475183]   Arg0:   00000000f9a8990a <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
[    0.475186] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475190] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475365] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475369] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475369]   Local0: 00000000f2777926 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475372] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475372]   Arg0:   00000000ae7599be <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000004
[    0.475375] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475379] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475416] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475420] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475420]   Local0: 0000000044228069 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475423] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475423]   Arg0:   00000000653fa0f9 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000005
[    0.475426] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475429] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475465] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475468] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475469]   Local0: 0000000021270c3e <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475471] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475472]   Arg0:   00000000ae7599be <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000006
[    0.475474] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475478] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475517] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475520] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475521]   Local0: 0000000045694f77 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475523] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475523]   Arg0:   00000000653fa0f9 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000007
[    0.475526] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475530] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475566] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475570] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475570]   Local0: 00000000a56b68b3 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475572] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475573]   Arg0:   00000000ae7599be <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000008
[    0.475575] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475579] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475616] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475620] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475620]   Local0: 000000001229a1ce <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475622] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475623]   Arg0:   00000000653fa0f9 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000009
[    0.475625] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475629] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475665] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475669] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475669]   Local0: 000000006afbda99 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475672] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475672]   Arg0:   00000000ae7599be <Obj>           Integer 000000000000000A
[    0.475675] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475678] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475713] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475716] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475717]   Local0: 0000000019e39a51 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475719] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475720]   Arg0:   00000000653fa0f9 <Obj>           Integer 000000000000000B
[    0.475722] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475726] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475761] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475765] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475765]   Local0: 000000007de99b59 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475768] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475768]   Arg0:   00000000ae7599be <Obj>           Integer 000000000000000C
[    0.475771] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475774] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475810] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.475814] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.475814]   Local0: 00000000d928d469 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.475817] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.475817]   Arg0:   00000000653fa0f9 <Obj>           Integer 000000000000000D
[    0.475820] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475823] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.475970] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.475973] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    0.475974] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    0.476001] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    0.476002] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.476002] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.476003] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-39-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.476004] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.476164] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.476174] hub 4-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    0.476342] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.476347] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PLD]
[    0.476348] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PLD]
[    0.476350] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SSP2._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.476396] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.476400] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.476401]   Local0: 000000004200aac3 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.476404] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.476404]   Arg0:   00000000ae7599be <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000011
[    0.476408] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.476412] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SSP3._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.476452] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000008) is beyond end of object (length 0x1) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.476456] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [XPLD]:
[    0.476456]   Local0: 000000007ec71f6d <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    0.476459] Initialized Arguments for Method [XPLD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.476459]   Arg0:   0000000022ec78ca <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000012
[    0.476462] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.XPLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.476466] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SSP4._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.476560] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    0.480745] i8042: Detected active multiplexing controller, rev 1.1
[    0.482468] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.482471] serio: i8042 AUX0 port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.482488] serio: i8042 AUX1 port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
################################################################################################
Next Problem(what are all these warnings?)
################################################################################################
[    0.545457] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    0.545459] Run /init as init process
[    0.619356] acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[    0.645144] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000184F (\GPIS) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645150] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000187F (\PMIX) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645155] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000187F (\PMIO) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645159] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    0.645162] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C40-0x0000000000001C4F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C7F (\GPXX) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645166] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C40-0x0000000000001C4F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645170] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    0.645171] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C7F (\GPXX) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645175] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645178] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645182] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    0.645183] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C7F (\GPXX) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645187] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645191] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20190816/utaddress-204)
[    0.645194] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
###############################################################################################
Next Problem( notice the 5 sec Delay)
###############################################################################################

[   15.759250] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   15.759251] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   20.941972] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066512.934:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=808 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   20.942481] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066512.934:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=810 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   20.942484] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066512.934:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=810 comm="apparmor_parser"
##############################################################################################
Next Problem
##############################################################################################
[   21.146895] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066513.134:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=813 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.195210] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066513.186:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=817 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   35.096850] kauditd_printk_skb: 37 callbacks suppressed
[   35.096854] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066527.082:49): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=989 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[   38.234128] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32
[   38.246073] wlp2s0: send auth to 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32 (try 1/3)
[   38.249554] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   38.256916] wlp2s0: associate with 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32 (try 1/3)

################################################################################################
Next Problem(The delay b/w certain programs keep on increasing... are these Normal or some bugs)
################################################################################################

[   38.262552] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   38.262674] wlp2s0: associated
[   38.479476] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[   50.768031] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   50.768034] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   50.768040] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   61.997067] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4054.0003: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[   62.848527] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   75.220804] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   84.117555] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   85.494720] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066577.048:50): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/8140/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2143 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[   90.671612] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066582.225:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/mime.cache" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   90.671649] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066582.225:52): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/globs2" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   90.671684] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066582.225:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/magic" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   90.671709] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066582.225:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/aliases" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   90.671733] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066582.225:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/subclasses" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   90.671757] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066582.225:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/icons" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   90.671786] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066582.225:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/generic-icons" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   90.672606] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066582.229:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/gnome/defaults.list" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   91.766942] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066583.321:59): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled" pid=2143 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   91.902451] audit: type=1107 audit(1593066583.458:60): pid=890 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.12" pid=2143 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=891 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  105.344856] kauditd_printk_skb: 8 callbacks suppressed
[  105.344858] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066596.906:69): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/mime.cache" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  105.344863] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066596.906:70): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/globs2" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
################################################################################################
Next Problem(55 seconds delay)
################################################################################################
[  105.344882] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066596.906:73): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/subclasses" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  105.344890] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066596.906:74): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/icons" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  105.344899] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066596.906:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/generic-icons" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  160.437251] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066652.001:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/mime.cache" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  160.437256] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066652.001:77): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/globs2" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  160.437265] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066652.001:78): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/magic" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  160.437277] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066652.001:79): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/aliases" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  160.437287] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066652.001:80): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/subclasses" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  160.437297] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066652.001:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/icons" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  160.437307] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066652.001:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/generic-icons" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  164.307802] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066655.869:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/Yaru/icon-theme.cache" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  164.307808] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066655.869:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/Yaru/8x8/emblems/" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

################################################################################################
################################################################################################
Next Problem(is this normal??)
################################################################################################
################################################################################################
[  165.558107] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066657.121:811): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  165.558110] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066657.121:812): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/animations/" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  165.558986] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066657.121:813): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  165.558989] audit: type=1400 audit(1593066657.121:814): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/" pid=2143 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 6292.133743] perf: interrupt took too long (2503 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[ 8019.289708] wlp2s0: deauthenticated from 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32 (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 8059.520211] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 8059.629682] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=0220, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 8059.629688] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 8059.822674] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 8060.048227] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 8061.928063] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32
[ 8061.939958] wlp2s0: send auth to 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32 (try 1/3)
[ 8061.943003] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 8061.944115] wlp2s0: associate with 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32 (try 1/3)
[ 8061.949670] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2e:fd:ab:d6:c8:32 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 8061.949783] wlp2s0: associated
[ 8061.965616] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 8065.381323] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=0220, bcdDevice= 0.02
[ 8065.381328] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 8065.532669] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[ 8065.931391] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 8065.931404] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 8065.931415] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: I would check your *file-system table* (`/etc/fstab`) for incorrect entries, also look for details on what is slow (`systemd-analyze blame`)

Comment: https://justpaste.it/9ry4r   i uploaded the output here as the AskUbuntu post has 30,000 character limit

Comment: @guiverc i have added the systemd-analyze blame output at a url to the question and above comment

Comment: your system is a bit slower than mine but not by more than a few seconds in  systemd-analyze blame 1-3sec slower for each line,i am running i3 cpu and 8gig ram.

Comment: @trondhansen do the seconds in the system-d analyze blame show the difference in time or the time at which it took from start time?... also i have intel i5 and 4gb ram...should i not worry about the ACPI bios errors and warning in the dmesg output?..why does it extend to 8000 seconds in ddmesg output? more than 10 mins?